# Como chamar o método startActivity() em um Adapter?

Tags: android

Então estou com um problema que redirecionar para outra activity no click do botão, só que dentro de uma classe adapter não consigo fazer nada, não consigo chamar startActivity().

```
public class ProdutoRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProdutoRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private final List<Produto> produtos;

public ProdutoRecyclerAdapter(final List<Produto> produtos) {
    this.produtos = produtos;
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgProduto;
    TextView txtTitulo;
    TextView txtDescricao;
    TextView txtPreco;
    Button btnDetalhes;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imgProduto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgProduto);
        txtTitulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);
        txtDescricao = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
        txtPreco = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPreco);
        btnDetalhes = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDetalhes);
        btnDetalhes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Aqui não chama o startActivity
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

[startActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) é um método da classe [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), para poder usá-lo tem de ter acesso a uma instância dessa classe.

Para que tenha um *Context* disponível no seu *Adapter* declare um construtor que o receba:

```
public class ProdutoRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProdutoRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private final List<Produto> produtos;
private final Context context;

public ProdutoRecyclerAdapter(final List<Produto> produtos, final Context context) {
    this.produtos = produtos;
    this.context = context;
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgProduto;
    TextView txtTitulo;
    TextView txtDescricao;
    TextView txtPreco;
    Button btnDetalhes;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imgProduto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgProduto);
        txtTitulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);
        txtDescricao = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
        txtPreco = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPreco);
        btnDetalhes = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDetalhes);
        btnDetalhes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Aqui chama o startActivity,  
                //mas antes crie um Intent.

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Ao instanciar o *Adapter*, além de passar ao construtor a `List<Produto>`, passe também a sua *Activity*.

Comment: Valeu mais eu fiz diferente peguei a view do onClick e puxei por ela o context e dei startActivity e funcionou, mais desse jeito também da certo valeu